# Constructor or conversion is called?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

For example

```
struct A
{
    A(B const& b) {}  // function 1
};

struct B
{
    operator A() const { return A(); } // function 2
};
```

And

```
B b;
A a(b); // function 1 is called.
```

Any way to make `a` to be constructed or converted by function 2?

Comment: I don't think so; overload resolution chooses 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written it, overload resolution choses `A`'s ctor. If you wrote it slightly differently:

`A a = b`

It would cause an error that the conversion is ambiguous. If you changed `A`'s ctor to be explicit:

`explicit A(const B&) {}`

It would then choose `B`'s conversion operator instead of `A`'s ctor with the line `A a = b`, and call `A`'s ctor with the line `A a(b)`

If you really want to force `B`'s conversion operator, you can always call it explicitly:

`A a = b.operator A();`